# Spring Data JPA mapping nested entities

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I'm a little bit confused about using projections in Spring Data JPA.
I wanted to optimize my queries by **requesting only needed columns (preferably) in one query**, and I thought that using projections is a good idea. But it seems that projection with nested projection becomes open and requests all columns and further nesting is impossible.

I've tried to find a solution with `@Query` (cannot find how to map nested lists), `@EntityGraph` (cannot find how to request only specified column) and `@SqlResultSetMapping` (cannot find how to make mapping nested lists), but it hasn't worked for me.
Is there any solution except receiving `List<Object[]>` and manually mapping?

I have the next entities classes (simplified for the question):

```
public class TestAttempt{
    private Long id;
    private User targetUser;
    private Test test;
}

public class Test{
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private Set<Question> questions;
}

public class Question{
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private Test test;
}
```

And I wanted to write something like this (it can be just `TestAttempt` with `null` in unused fields):

```
public interface TestAttemptList {
    Long getId();
    Test getTest();

    interface Test {
        String getName();

        List<Question> getQuestions();

        interface Question {
            String getName();
        }
    }
}

public interface TestAttemptRepository extends JpaRepository<TestAttempt, Long> {
    List<TestAttemptList> getAllByTargetUserId(Long targetUserId);
}
```

And in result get something like this:

```
{
    id: 1,
    test: {
        name: test1,
        questions: [{
            name: quest1
        }, {
            name: quest2
        }]
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JPA Projection with custom collection property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56164938/jpa-projection-with-custom-collection-property)

Comment: @AlanHay, I've tried to write query manually but it seems that Spring can't map nested entities with 2 fields and I get _Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS_, and even when I get rid of the questions field in the query, the _getTest()_ method throws _IllegalAccessException_ as the framework maps test as String

Answer (score 0):

Ive done something like this... You'll have your repository interfaces which will extend CrudRepository et. al. with the full objects (TestAttempt etc) You define your projections separately. The projection interfaces can contain other projection interfaces (TestAttemptSummary can contain a TestSummary) When the projection interface is used within the given repository the defined methods are applied to the object type the repository is configured for. Something like this.

```
public interface TestAttemptSummary {
    Long getId();
    TestSummary getTest();
}

public interface TestSummary {
    String getName();
    List<QuestionSummary> getQuestions();
}

public interface QuestionSummary {
    String getName();
}

public interface TestAttemptRepository extends CrudRepository<TestAttempt, Long> {
    TestAttemptSummary getTestAttemptSummary();
}
```

Comment: I tried to do this. But questions don't fetch via query (generated query looks like this : _select ... from test_attempt ta inner join test t on ta.test_id = t.id_), so I get LazyInitializationException when I try to getQuestions() from Test.